# QSharedPointer and QObject::deleteLater

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr, qobject, qsharedpointer

I have a situation where a `QSharedPointer` managed object signalizes that it has finished it's purpose and is ready for deletion soon (after execution left the function emitting my `readyForDeletion` signal). When working with *normal* pointers, I'd just call `QObject::deleteLater` on the object, however this isn't possible with a `QSharedPointer`-managed instance. My workaround is the following:

```
template<typename T>
class QSharedPointerContainer : public QObject
{
   QSharedPointer<T> m_pSharedObj;

public:

   QSharedPointerContainer(QSharedPointer<T> pSharedObj)
      : m_pSharedObj(pSharedObj)
   {} // ==> ctor

}; // ==> QSharedPointerContainer

template<typename T>
void deleteSharedPointerLater(QSharedPointer<T> pSharedObj)
{
   (new QSharedPointerContainer<T>(pSharedObj))->deleteLater();
} // ==> deleteSharedPointerLater
```

This works well, however there's a lot of overhead using this method (allocating a new `QObject` and so on). Is there any better solution to handle such situations?

Comment: So you have an object that is managed by shared ownership (there are several objects that claim ownership) yet at the same time it manages its own lifetime (by having a readyForDeletion signal)? Sounds to me like you've got a really messed up ownership situation. Instead of looking for workarounds, try to clear up who is really responsible for the object and therefore who should delete it.

Comment: I have to agree with @Sabastian. I was about to post a similar comment when his came in. If your object keeps track of when it is safe to be deleted, just use a plain old pointer, and handle the `readyForDeletion` signal on whatever class creates the object in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. In my actual program things are a lot more complicated, however, taking a look at the abstract problem, it becomes clear that using a QSharedPointer in this context is no good idea at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `QSharedPointer` [constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedpointer.html#QSharedPointer-3) with the `Deleter` :

> The deleter parameter specifies the custom deleter for this object.
>   The custom deleter is called, instead of the operator delete(), when
>   the strong reference count drops to 0. This is useful, for instance,
>   for calling deleteLater() on a QObject instead:

```
 QSharedPointer<MyObject> obj =
         QSharedPointer<MyObject>(new MyObject, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using [QPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) instead of [QSharedPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html), citing the documentation:

> The QPointer class is a template class that provides guarded pointers to QObject.
>
> A guarded pointer, QPointer, behaves like a normal C++ pointer T *, except that it is automatically set to 0 when the referenced object is destroyed (unlike normal C++ pointers, which become "dangling pointers" in such cases). T must be a subclass of QObject.